How to write an Apple Script to check "Allow unsigned extensions" in Safari settings automatically?
I wrote a Safari extension for myself but I am not an apple developer, so everytime I close my safari it will take out my extension, and I would have to go into settings to turn on "Allow unsigned extensions" again.
So, I decided to write a mac script to do all that in one go. I was able to have it click into developer menu of Safari, but I just couldn't figure out how to get it to click the check box.
I wrote this code, evething works up until the final lines where I try to click the check box:
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        set frontmost to true
        delay 1
        click menu item "Settings…" of menu "Safari" of menu bar 1
        delay 1
        click button "Developer" of toolbar 1 of window 1
        delay 1
    end tell
    tell process "Safari"
        tell window "Developer"
            click checkbox "Allow unsigned extensions"
            
        end tell
    end tell
end tell


It return this error message:

System Events got an error: Can’t get checkbox "Allow unsigned extensions" of window "Developer" of process "Safari".

Like I was able to get to this part of the Safari menu, but I just couldn't figure out how to get it to click that "Allow unsigned extensions"checkbox.

In Sonoma that checkbox is buried further down in a couple of groups - what OS are you running?

@red_menace Sonoma 14.3

You can trigger the Developer settings in the Safari menu, and then click on the check box. It will then require you to confirm this by authenticating via Touch ID or password.  Below example tested on Sonoma 14.5.
I used UI Browser (paid app) to find the correct UI Hierarchy. You can also use other means like recursively inspecting, or Accessibility Inspector more detailed inspection and it's free.
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari"
    set frontmost to true
    try
        click (first menu item of menu 1 of menu bar item "Develop" of menu bar 1 whose title starts with "Developer Settings")
    end try

    click checkbox "Allow unsigned extensions" of group 1 of group 1 of front window
end tell

